# How does one obtain Inquisition Points in Dragon Age Inquisition?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I noticed in the Dragon Age Inquisition war table there are options to purchase (what I think are called) party abilities which cost Inquisition Points, however I am at a loss on where these points come from.

How does one obtain Inquisition Points in Dragon Age Inquisition?

Does there exist possible farming methods to obtain them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are called Inquisition Perks. You get one new Perk every time your influence bar fills up and reaches a new level.

The main way to get more influence to fill your bar and gain perks is to complete missions. More important missions will gain you more influence than smaller missions. Finding new agents throughout Thedas will also gain you a decent amount of influence. Some advisor missions will also reward you with a bit of influence.

Answer (score 3):

Kareen's answer is true in theory, but it is not a very good way to farm influence. A far better way to get influence fast is to farm gold in whatever method you prefer (killing giants in Emerald Graves for example) and then buying influence tomes from the merchant in Skyhold.

These give massive amounts of influence upon being bought, and unlike missions, can be repeated up to 10 times per tome.

Comment: I agree Theik, it is faster to gain Inquisition Perk points by buying influence & power from the merchant "Farris The Representative" at Skyhold rather than completing missions; For example, I unlocked "Deft Hands, Fine Tools" perk by acquiring 4 agents in Secrets, but I didn't have a point to spend for the perk. So instead of completing a number of long or short missions to gain influence for the perk point, I simply went to the merchant & bought the influence & got my point.