# What items count towards the inventory limit?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

There is a 60-item limit for your inventory in Dragon Age: Inquisition. But what types of items count towards your limit?

There are:

- Weapons
- Armor
- Accessories
- Upgrades
- Crafting Materials
- Valuables
- Weapons Schematics
- Armor Schematics
- Recipes

Do they ALL count towards the limit? Or just weapons, armor, and accessories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recipes, schematics and crafting materials don't count toward the item limit. Only weapons, armor, accessories, upgrades and valuables do. Valuables that are stacked will only count for one.

Don't forget that is possible to increase the limit of things you can carry with the tailor Perks. There is also a storage chest in Skyhold for weapons, armor, accessories and upgrades.

Comment: Btw, how can I find or what is the "tailor perks"?

Comment: @Zarathustrax You get a perk every time your influence levels up. You can cash them at the war table. The tailor perks are in the Connections section (Josephine's). [See this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/193271/7091).